# How to clear Apache cache in XAMMP?

Tags: apache, caching, xampp

How can I clear apache cache in xammp?

I tried the 'htcacheclean -r' command, but it's always generated error.

If I know well the apache can't cache the files/ scripts, but a system administrator said this: 'The apache casheing the site, so clear the apache(!) cache.'.

[image: Open Shell]

[image: Generated error]

Comment: why did you want to clear  the cache? what error did it generate? Can you post it?what are you working on?

Comment: I working on a website and i'm useing leaflet.js, but if i change the map coordinates the website don't change. I clear browser cache, but this isn't working. The system administrator said the problem is the apache cache. He don't know why but the apache cache the whole site.

Comment: have you tried mod_cache?

Comment: @aizele How can i set it?

Comment: what apache version are you using?

Comment: Try restarting the Apache service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this:

Use mod_cache at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cache.html

```
CacheDisable /local_files
```

Description: Disable caching of specified URLs Syntax: CacheDisable url-string Context: server config, virtual host

Answer (score 0):

Try this if others not working:

`htcacheclean -p C:\xampp\htdocs\yourproject -rv -L 1000M`

In this way, you specify the `-p` path clearly, not to expect xampp to find that path.
The `-r` = Clean thoroughly. This assumes that the Apache web server is
not running. This option is mutually exclusive with the -d
option and implies -t.
The `-v` = Be verbose and print statistics. This option is mutually
exclusive with the -d option.
The `-L 1000M` = Specify LIMIT as the total disk cache inode limit.(in Megabytes)

Comment: From Review:  Code-only or Command-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to people with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks